# NETGEAR router-firewall setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, firewall

I have a NETGEAR WNDR3400 and it is connected to a NETGEAR FSV338. Do I need both the router and firewall to protect my network, or does the router act as a firewall too? In addition, the firewall and router seem to both be providing DHCP is there a way to have only one perform NAT and DHCP to put the firewall, router and clients all on one subnet?

Comment: As far as NAT/Firewall is concerned, you really only need one, and I would stick to the higher class FSV338.  If you need WiFi, just enter the configuration of the WNDR3400 and disabled DHCP and then run an Ethernet cable from one of the LAN ports to the FSV338.

Comment: Yes I need wifi so I need the router too. Do I disable NAT on the router?

Comment: You don't need to.  Like I said, you should plug the Eithernet cable into one of the LAN ports on the routner (not the WAN), so the WiFi router will not be doing an NAT.

Comment: Thank you. And also I seem be, in the configuration I had before, the following DOS attack under the router's log: [DoS attack: ACK Scan] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [attacker]. Since in the old config the router was getting this, does that mean the firewall is not working correctly?